# Diophantine equation $x^2+y^2+1=xyz$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $x,y,z$ be positive integers such that $x^2+y^2+1=xyz$.
>   Show that $z=3.$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115272/let-x-and-y-be-positive-integers-such-that-xy-mid-x2y21

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried [Vieta Jumping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping)? I think its's a good method for approaching this kind of problems.