# Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be natural numbers satisfying $x^2 + y^2 + 1 = xyz$. Prove that $z = 3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, vieta-jumping

> Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be natural numbers satisfying $x^2 + y^2 + 1 = xyz$. Prove that $z = 3$.

I have managed to show that $z$ is a multiple of $3$ by looking at it modulo $3$ but not sure how to show $z=3$. Any tips?

Comment: It is Vieta jumping  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping ; giving a fixed $z,$ we may reduce $x,y$ until certain inequalities are satisfied. This is also a case in Hurwitz (1907) http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf   I guess I will write it this way: with $$  w^2 + x^2 + y^2 = zwxy $$ in natural numbers, the legal values for $z$ are $z = 1,3.$ Furthermore, when $z=1,$ all possible values of $w,x,y$ are divisible by $3.$ This is ruled out in your question, which uses $w=1$

Comment: see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number

Comment: good, it is the Example in the section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping#Constant_descent_Vieta_jumping  I don't need to write it out.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219

Comment: See also [Diophantine equation $x^2+y^2+1=xyz$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/941759) and [Let $x$ and $y$ be positive integers such that $xy \mid x^2+y^2+1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115272) Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%20%2B%201%20%3D%20xyz%24&p=1).

Answer (score 1):

One could go about this in the following way: If $x = y$, then the equation becomes

\begin{align*}
2x^2 + 1 &= x^2 z
\end{align*}
where the left-hand side is congruent to $1$ (mod $x$) and the right-hand side is congruent to $0$. It follows immediately that $x = 1$, and consequently that $z = 3$.

Now, suppose that $y > x$ (with no loss of generality). Then we can write $y = x+k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. Substituting this into the equation, we see that

\begin{align*}
x^2 + x^2 + 2kx + k^2 &= x(x+k)z \\
&\equiv 0
\end{align*}
(mod $x$). Consequently,

\begin{align*}
x \mid k^2 = (y-x)^2 = y^2 - 2yx + x^2 \equiv y^2
\end{align*}
(mod $x$).

Thus there is some natural $b$ so that $y^2 = bx$. Using this, we find that

\begin{align*}
x^2 + bx + 1 = xyz.
\end{align*}
The right-hand side $xyz$ is divisible by $x$, but also $xyz - 1$ is divisible by $x$, since this is equal to $x^2 + bx$. Thus we must have $x = 1$. Now the original equation becomes

\begin{align*}
y^2 + 2 &= yz\\
&\Updownarrow \\
y^2 - yz + 2 &= 0.
\end{align*}
This quadratic equation in $y$ must have a square discriminant since $y$ is assumed to be a natural number. Hence
\begin{align*}
D &= (-z)^2 - 4\cdot 1 \cdot 2 \\
&= z^2 - 8
\end{align*}
is a square. This is only achieved for $z = 3$:

\begin{align*}
z^2 - 8 &= r^2 \\
&\Updownarrow \\
(z-r)(z+r) &= 8 \\
&\Downarrow \\
z-r &\in \lbrace 1, 2\rbrace, \\
z+r &\in \lbrace 4, 8 \rbrace.
\end{align*}
The only possibility here is that $z = 3$ and $r = 1$.

Thus, in any case, $z = 3$.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use Vietas formulas directly to do this problem. Assuming a minimal solution then creating a smaller one if y>x thus y=x is the only possibility.

Comment: Actually (x,y,z) = (1,2,3) is also a solution.

Comment: This needs some clarification: you can prove that if a minimal counterexample exists (i.e., with $z\ne3$), then it must satisfy $y=x$ and hence $z=3$, which is a contradiction, proving that we must have $z=3$ for all solutions.  As BaconAndX's solution shows, this does not prove that $y=x$ for all solutions.