# When is $x^2+y^2+1=xyz$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Essentially, when is $\dfrac{x^2 +y^2+1}{xy}$ a positive integer?

I've tried many approaches such as considering the above equation as a quadratic in $x$ or $y$ but I haven't had much success. The only solutions I could find were $x=1$, $y=1$ and $z=3$.

A similar problem:
I know that the only solutions to $\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{xy}$ to equal a positive integer is for $x$ and $y$ to both be one. This is pretty much considering when a number, not necessarily an integer, and it's inverse sum to make a positive whole number. However, the problem is a slight variation, it asks when a number $\frac{p}{q}$ summed with it's inverse $\frac{q}{p}$ plus $\frac{1}{pq}$ is a whole number.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you find this problem?

Comment: My friend told me his teacher gave it to him as a challenge

Comment: "giving you all solutions" is a bit of an overstatement, at lest there is work to do, see my answer. But your observation is crucial. +1

Comment: @A.Pongrácz You are right, it is more of a first step towards all solutions.

Comment: Also quite interestingly, as one of the comments in linked questions suggests, it is linked to Fibonacci numbers, since $F_n^2+F_{n+2}^2 + 1= 3 F_{n}F_{n+2}$ for $n$ odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this post, suggested in the comments: [Let $x$ and $y$ be positive integers such that $xy \mid x^2+y^2+1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115272/let-x-and-y-be-positive-integers-such-that-xy-mid-x2y21)

we have $z=3$.

$x^2 - 3y\cdot x + (y^2+1)=0$, so the discriminant is a perfect square: 
$D=5y^2-4=t^2$. This is a Pell-type equation with infinitely many solutions: e.g., $y=2, t=4$, or $y=5, t=11$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation

Comment: Thanks so much, you're the best

Comment: the best presentation related to "Vieta Jumping" is Hurwitz(1907) and the German is on the easy side; http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf  If curious, you might view the roughly 45 questions with tag https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vieta-jumping